# Epson Perfection 3200 PHOTO on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit

My upgrade to Windows 7 64-bit is *almost* perfect... I have been able to find 64-bit drivers for all my existing hardware, except for my beloved [Epson Perfection 3200 PHOTO](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=20882&prodoid=27766185&infoType=Downloads&platform=Windows64).

What are my options, short of dumping either my perfectly working scanner or my *almost* perfectly working Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots and lots of searches I finally found a solution that works well, without having to download 500MB of bloatware ("XP mode"): [EPSON PERFECTION 3200 PHOTO on 64-bit Windows 7](http://www.softwarecandy.com/shop/free-tips/make-your-epson-perfection-3200-photo-work-with-64-bit-windows-7).

What a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to run this scanner in the Windows Compatibility Center to see what drivers are available? http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/default.aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried and curiously, all ESPON PERFECTION models are supported in Windows 7 64-bit -- except for the 3200 version. What makes it so different (from the 3170, for example)?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Windows 7 is Professional, Ultimate, or Enterprise you could try [XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode) to get their scanning software, etc. installed.

I've had luck doing this for legacy HP multi-function devices.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your reply. Do I understand you correctly that XP Mode works for device drivers too?

Comment: Yup, it's a full version of XP running in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks. Downloading at least 500MB for one missing driver seems an overkill. Dumping my perfectly working scanner is becoming more and more attractive. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Virtual XP Mode within Windows 7 does not work for Epson 3200. There is a workaround where you can download the software for Epson 4990 scanner and tweak it a bit. Here is the site that offers this instruction.

http://www.softwarecandy.com/shop/free-tips/make-your-epson-perfection-3200-photo-work-with-64-bit-windows-7

I have Epson 3200 scanner and Epson 2200 printer, just upgraded to Windows 7 and find that Epson doesn't provide a driver for either.  I might keep my old XP computer just for doing my photo work, using scanner & pro photo printer. I certainly don't want to throw away my perfectly operational and fairly high end printer and scanner!